# How can we read multiple sequence files in Apache Flink parallely as Batch Job

Tags: dataset, apache-flink, sequencefile

I have a use case of reading sequence files as a Batch job in Flink Dataset. The files are stored in S3 bucket which I have to consume in a Flink Dataset. I am not able to read the files by providing comma(,) separated file paths to read in the Dataset. I cannot read the data in file using a loop as there are a lot of files in the bucket. Also the `union` function for Flink Datasets seems to fail after few iterations. Can someone help me out with creating a custom Sequence file reader which will work for this case as provided in Spark.